# Find date and color it (PHP)

Tags: php, date

i got a page, there is in one variable ($content) the hole text which is shown.

In this variable, **$content**, are several dates.

I want to bold all dates - so:

$content = "27.09.2014 - abc- 03.04.2011 - def11.11.2011 92849ajsdasd"

should be detect **27.09.2014;03.04.2011;11.11.2011**

and $content should be ="**27.09.2014** - abc- **03.04.2011** - def**11.11.2011** 92849ajsdasd"

Is this possible to realise this with PHP?

Thanks,
Pohyal Stori

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression search and replacement:

```
$content = "27.09.2014 - abc- 03.04.2011 - def11.11.2011 92849ajsdasd";
$content = preg_replace("/\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}/", "<b>\\0</b>", $content);
```